# Async pipe does not seem to listen to Subject before onChanges

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

Component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'widget.ng.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

  readonly purchases$ = of([]);

  readonly refunds$ = new Subject<Refund[]>();

  constructor() {
    //    this.refunds$.subscribe();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.refunds$.next([]);
```

Template:

```
<div #containerDiv>
  <collapsible-group>
    <div collapsible #collapsibleDiv>
      <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab>
          <ng-container *ngIf="purchases$ | async as purchases; else loading">
            <purchases-table
                [purchases]="purchases">
            </purchases-table>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab>
          <ng-container *ngIf="refunds$ | async as refunds; else loading">
              <refunds-table [refunds]="refunds">
              </refunds-table>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>

      <!-- Loading State -->
      <ng-template #loading>
        Loading...
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </collapsible-group>
</div>
```

In this code: `purchases` loads as expected, while `refunds` does not. However, if I uncomment the line in the constructor, `refunds` will also work as expected.

The async pipe does not seem to subscribe to the subject, or it possibly fails to subscribe to the subject before ngOnChanges. Is this right?

Possibly has to do with OnPush?

Comment: Did you try using a `BehaviorSubject`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a behavior subject instead as you can give it the empty array as the initial value and you don't need to worry about when next is called.

```
refunds$ = new BehaviorSubject<Refund[]>([]);
```

Subscriptions to subjects will only get values that are emitted after the subscription happens, BehaviorSubjects get the last emitted value when subscribing.

Answer (score 1):

You have been the victim of two cooperating flaws in the software.

First is `ngOnChanges()`.  It is not called exactly when you'd think.  It is called only if there are @Input values being set, and the first time it called, the call occurs *before* the call to `ngOnInit()` and before some of the initialization of the template is done.

The other is `Subject`.  Since it is the base class for several other Subject in RxJS, you'd naturally think it is the default class to you.  Not so!  In fact, it is rare to use the base `Subject`, since it has no buffering ability at all.  When writing Angular code, you generally want to use `BehaviorSubject` (when you have a initial value) or `ReplaySubject` (when you don't).

I created a [Stackblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subject-before-onchanges?file=src/app/widget.component.ts) to illustrate your alternatives, with three made-up Observables.

You can continue using `Subject`, which has the disadvantage of not working at all.

You can use a `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` and continue to trigger it off the `ngOnChanges()`.  This works... probably.  `ngOnChanges()` is a little odd (in my opinion), but it behaves systematically and you can get it to do what you need.

My personal preference is to use  a `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` and trigger it off an `@Input set()`.  I think this is a good mixture of readability, efficiency, and flexibility.  See [here](https://medium.com/@malvoliosf/matthias-thank-you-for-this-8b798a07574b) for more information.